# Open source component to develop multi-page PDFs from HTML

Tags: asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

Does anyone know of an open source solution for generating multi-page PDFs from HTML server-side?  iTextSharp etc. are all about composing page-by-page.  Please don't suggest a PDF Printer.

I know of store-bought solutions that achieve this very well, but there has got to be a free component.

Regards.

Comment: Why can't you use the server executable for PDFCreator (a PDF printer)?

Comment: What do you mean by page-by-page? I think iText can produce multi-page PDFs from HTML.

Comment: Because that's not going to provide for a high capacity solution.

Comment: iTextSharp can, but what I want to do is simply say here's some HTML ... stretch it across however many pages it needs to fit.

Comment: What commercial option already provides this functionality? Maybe if we have a better understanding of what you're looking for, we can make better suggestions...

Comment: This product works perfectly, but not every client I have can afford to drop $1100 on a feature that is rarely used.

http://www.html-to-pdf.net

Comment: Because there are so many questions similar to this one but not quite the same, I decided to try to collect a complete list of HTML to PDF converters into a community wiki question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178448/list-of-html-to-pdf-converters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if you consider this a "PDF Printer", but I stumbled onto this one yesterday and it seems to work great.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Here is a company's experience: http://beebole.com/blog/erlang/convert-html-to-pdf-with-full-css-support-an-opensource-alternative-based-on-webkit/

Please share any experiences you find from any of these answers. Good luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Great find!! This is an epic solution.  I can wrap this into something very useful with little effort.

Answer (score 1):

[XHTML2PDF/Pisa](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/)  is a great Python project that does just want you want.  It is dual licensed XHTML2PDF is dual-licensed with the GNU General Public License Version 2.0 (GPLv2)  or a commercial license

Comment: It has worked flawlessly for me for the past year. I *HIGHLY* recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu Linux 10.04

- `$ html2ps -W b -U -u -O -n -o index.ps index.html`
- `$ ps2pdf index.ps`

For example from this file:
[GIMP 2.6it html.tar.bz2 online manual](ftp://ftp.gimp.org/pub/gimp/help/gimp-help-2.6.0-html-it.tar.bz2)
it generate a 1800 pages, 19 MB PDF crossliked single file.
Open solutions work always better

Answer (score 1):

You can use PhantomJS. That works for sure and is free!

Comment: Nice idea as a route for this.

Answer (score 0):

[Prince](http://www.princexml.com/) does just that, and generates beautiful outputs too. For example, to see how it deals with a page on wikipedia, try (after installing prince):

```
prince --no-author-style -s http://www.princexml.com/howcome/2008/wikipedia/wiki2.css http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usa -o usa.pdf
```

Comment: Prince is very good but I don't think it is either open source or free.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I had the impression it was open source.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if one such library is available for asp or .net but there is one Java library called [PDFBox](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/pdfbox.html) which is now in the Apache incubator project. You could give it a try

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using XSLT-FO, then use [fop](http://projects.apache.org/projects/fop.html) to generate the PDF.